# How can I rewrite all requests for one domain to a subfolder (htaccess)? Existing code not quite working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules in an .htaccess file. The idea is any requests to www.site.com should be routed to the 'folder' subfolder, but any other domains should be unaffected.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

This works for the index file in /folder/, but I have images and css in /folder/assets/ and these are not loading.

Any idea how to pass on the rewrite to the entire contents of /folder/, including files in /folder/assets/ ?

Comment: Do you have rewrite rules in other htaccess files? Are there htaccess files in the `/folder/assets/` directory?

Comment: No, no other htaccess files...

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteBase /` directive? If not, add a / to `^/(.*)$`. If you do, remove the slash in front of folder/$1.

Comment: Then the rules will get applied to subfolders. How are your images and css linked?

Comment: @Wige. Yes I have `RewriteBase /`. Edited the code sample above.

Comment: @Jon they are linked via relative urls eg. `assets/img/image.jpg`

Comment: Pasting my rules into this htaccess linter http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ shows that images are being rewritten to `http://www.site.com/folder/assets/image.jpg`. I'm guessing that's where it's going wrong as the root should already be 'folder'?